# Generalization of the prime number theorem to other fields

Tags: prime-numbers

Is there a similar statement to the prime number theorem in other rings like $\mathbb{Z}[i]$ or $\mathbb{Z}[\omega]$.

Comment: Yes, see http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Landau_prime_ideal_theorem

Comment: Technicality: ${\bf Z}[i]$ is not a field, a fortiori, not a number field. It is the ring of integers in ${\bf Q}[i]$, which *is* a number field. Similarly for ${\bf Z}[\omega]$.

Comment: Ok. I will edit that.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, if $\mathcal O_K$ is the ring of integers in a number field $K$, 
and $\pi_K(x)$ denotes the number of non-zero primes ideals in $\mathcal O_K$
of norm $\leq x$, then $\pi_K(x) \sim x/\log x.$

The link in Siddharth Prasad's comment has more details.  The proof uses the
same $\zeta$-function techniques as the proof of the usual prime number theorem.